# clicklistener on the cardview android

Tags: android, xml

> So I have a cardview and don't have a recyclerview, which looks like this:

```
<androidx.cardview.widget.CardView
        android:layout_width="130dp"
        android:layout_height="140dp"
        android:layout_marginStart="40dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="130dp"
        android:foregroundGravity="center"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent">

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="100dp"
            android:background="#DA7B93">

            <ImageView
                android:layout_width="80dp"
                android:layout_height="80dp"
                android:layout_marginLeft="25dp"
                android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
                android:layout_marginRight="25dp"
                android:layout_marginBottom="10dp"
                android:src="@drawable/calculator"></ImageView>
        </LinearLayout>

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="42dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="100dp">

            <TextView
                android:layout_width="100dp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginLeft="15dp"
                android:layout_marginRight="15dp"
                android:fontFamily="@font/montserrat"
                android:text="Math problems"
                android:textSize="15sp"></TextView>
        </LinearLayout>
    </androidx.cardview.widget.CardView>
```

I was wondering if it is possible to add an onclicklistener without a recyclerview ?

thanks,

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**- If you want to display multiple CardViews:**

Your RecyclerView is the container that handles all the layouts and views processing. It handles the memory and stack flow of views. you can think of it as a bookshelf. Whereas the Cardview acts as a sub-container which holds all the views together that has to be a single child of the recycler view. You can think it of like the bookshelf categories like history, geography, maths ,etc.

As your question and the example mentioned above, you will need a cardview with a recyclerview to handle your views processing. This single cardview copy will be created for all your views with the help of RecyclerView itself. Thats the whole idea of RecyclerView.

**- If you want to use only Single CardView:**

```
CardView cardView = findViewById(R.id.card);
        cardView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                //your logic
            }
        });
```

Comment: can I not somehow pass the possition in and then detect which it is ?

Comment: position in the sense? you mean you will add multiple cardviews in the layout and then you want to set click events on each of them?

Comment: no, not like that I want to get the position like in the listview

Comment: See you r mentioning listview. you have your answer with yourself. RecyclerView is a far more better version of ListView. I know you are having a fear to try something new. Bt my friend thats where you will learn nd evolve! Happy Coding!

Answer (score 1):

Just set an id for your `CardView` likr `android:id="@+id/cardView_test`.

Then find it in your activity and set `onClickListener();`:

```
CardView cardView = findViewById(R.id.cardView_test);
card.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
      @Override
      public void onClick(View v) {
          // put your code here.
      }
});
```

Comment: thanks, but how can I get on which cardview I pressed ?

Comment: In `recyclerView` , inside of `onBind` method which you set up your views, put this `onClickListener`. The `recyclerView` knows which item is called.